# Flutter integration testing: can I start the test on any page? How?

Tags: flutter, testing, mobile, integration-testing, mobile-application

So I am testing an app that has multiple pages.

Sometimes, I just want to start a test from a page of choice.

However, I can't figure out how to do it.

Everywhere I look, everyone always starts their integration test at the beginning by calling `main()`.

This makes sense but my case is unique.  I tried to import the page that I want to start at and I tried calling the main class but I get the following error:

`The constructor returns type 'dynamic' that isn't of expected type 'widget'.`

My stack also states:

```
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#4      main.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///D:/WEBDEV/EndevStudios/MedicalApp/gshDevWork/medical-app-frontend/integration_test/basic_app_test.dart:94:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided one frame from package:stack_trace)
```

I think the class I'm trying to call isn't built that way.  Here's the beginning part of that code:

```
class WelcomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title = "Welcome!";
  final String titleDev = "Take Control of your Health!";
  final String boxDescription =
      "It is for information purposes only and help you access health professionals through virtual means as well as screen for a selection of diseases.";
  final String innerContainerTextTitle =
      "WARNING! This application is not a diagnosing tool.";
  final String descriptionTitle = 'App Features:';
  final String descriptionTitle1 =
      "Technology to analyze a selection of diseases.";
    final String descriptionTitle2 =
      "Resources to learn about different types of diseases; typical treatments; and management standards.";
  final String _titleImagePath = 'assets/appbar/diagnosis.webp';
  WelcomePage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: _buildAppbar(context),
      body: Container(
          width: displayWidth(context),
          height: displayHeight(context),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              // _logoImage(context),
              _welcomeInfo(context),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

In my test I was calling `app.WelcomePage();`

Answer (score 1):

you can start from any page by using **pumpWidget**, suppose here WelcomePage is not your first screen and you want to start test from WelcomePage then you can, but remember one thing it is compulsory to wrap your WelcomePage by the **MaterialApp** widget

```
testWidgets('Welcome Page Test', (WidgetTester tester) async {

/// build your app tree first

  await tester.pumpWidget(const MaterialApp(home:WelcomePage()));
```

/// then write your testing code for WelcomePage
});

Answer (score 0):

[integration_test](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction) will be used to run Screen/Page/Widget. This can be performed  by using `pumpWidget` method.

**pumpWidget:** Renders the UI from the given [widget]. so anything can be drawn on screen and tested.

**Example:**

```
testWidgets('Welcome Page Test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    /// Build our app and trigger a frame.
    
      await tester.pumpWidget(const WelcomePage());

   ///...
 });
```

Comment: Oh I see!  So I start on the page I want by passing the page through pumpWidget.  Thanks!